# How can i append data among appended element in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I wanna append all post likers name among a div like facebook postlikers name showing on hover.

Mother append jQuery :

```
 //alllikes users details
               $('.posted-area').append('\
               <div class="posted-footer posted-likes">\
               <ul>\
                 <li>\
                   <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#friend-list"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i> <span class="allpostlikers">Kash,Kruti and 5 Others</span></a>\
                 </li>\
               </ul>\
               </div>\
               <div class="other-list">\
               </div>\
               ');
```

2nd append which will show into class name other-list in Mother append :

```
 $.each(item.postlikes, function(key, likeruser){                       
                         $('.other-list').append('\
                          <ul>\
                           <li><a href="#"> '+likeruser.user_id+' </a></li>\
                            </ul>\
                          ');
                 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This:

```
//DEFINE THE PARENT AS AN OBJECT
var postedFooter = $('\
   <div class="posted-footer posted-likes">\
   <ul>\
     <li>\
       <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#friend-list"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i> <span class="allpostlikers">Kash,Kruti and 5 Others</span></a>\
     </li>\
   </ul>\
   </div>\
   <div class="other-list">\
   </div>\
');

//APPEND THE PARENT OBJECT
$('.posted-area').append($(postedFooter));

//APPEND THE OTHER LISTS TO THE PARENT OBJECT
$.each(item.postlikes, function(key, likeruser){                       
    $('.other-list', $(postedFooter)).append('\
        <ul>\
            <li><a href="#"> '+likeruser.user_id+' </a></li>\
        </ul>\
    ');
 });
```

Or another way is to pre compile and only do one append.

```
//DEFINE THE PARENT AS AN OBJECT
var postedFooter = '\
   <div class="posted-footer posted-likes">\
   <ul>\
     <li>\
       <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#friend-list"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i> <span class="allpostlikers">Kash,Kruti and 5 Others</span></a>\
     </li>\
   </ul>\
   </div>\
   <div class="other-list">';

$.each(item.postlikes, function(key, likeruser){                       
    postedFooter += '\
        <ul>\
            <li><a href="#"> '+likeruser.user_id+' </a></li>\
        </ul>\
    '
 });

postedFooter += '\
   </div>\
   </div>\
';

//APPEND THE PARENT OBJECT
$('.posted-area').append($(postedFooter));
```

Comment: other-list class li data isn't showing...I need to show all post likers- https://prnt.sc/5jzvRKnvV8Vu

Comment: When you run the `$.each(item.postLikes)` loop does it actually contain any data? if not then it would not append anything.

Comment: yes...on console i'm getting data, but not showing on hover